# multilayer concept

Tags: android

hello i want to know whether the multilayer concept is work in android. if yes means tell me how?

Comment: why again a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025259/multilayer-approach-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may get some idea here: [Layered SurfaceViews in a FrameLayout in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965724/layered-surfaceviews-in-a-framelayout-in-android)

And this: http://inphamousdevelopment.wordpress.com/2010/09/22/first-development-blog-post/

Both using

> addContentView()

which add view layers on top of each other.

Also in Frame layout it is possible to have views on top each other as layers.

Answer (score 0):

start with this http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/understanding-user-interface-android-part-1-layouts