# Android draw on camera preview

Tags: android, android-camera, glsurfaceview

I'm making a virtual reality application where the camera should detect faces, locate them and show their location on the camera preview.

I know of 3 ways to do it, I'd like to use GLSurfaceView to be as fast as possible ([according to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5010734/176269)), but currently I'm trying to draw on the *same* SurfaceView where the camera is using for its preview. My callback to draw on it would be `onFaceDetection` like so:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.FaceDetectionListener {
    Camera camera;
    SurfaceView svPreview;
    SurfaceHolder previewHolder;
    TextView tvInfo;
    Paint red;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        svPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.svPreview);
        tvInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);

        red = new Paint();
        red.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        red.setStrokeWidth(3);

        previewHolder = svPreview.getHolder();
        previewHolder.addCallback(this);
        previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        camera = Camera.open();
        try {
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            camera.setFaceDetectionListener(this);
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        // . . .
        camera.startPreview();
        camera.autoFocus(null);
        camera.startFaceDetection();
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        camera.stopFaceDetection();
        camera.cancelAutoFocus();
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }

    public void onFaceDetection(Face[] faces, Camera camera) {  
        tvInfo.setText("Faces: " + String.valueOf(faces.length));

        Canvas canvas = previewHolder.lockCanvas();
        for(int i=0; i < faces.length; i++) {
            Point leftEye = faces[i].leftEye;
            Point rightEye = faces[i].rightEye;
            // this is not working
            canvas.drawPoint(leftEye.x, leftEye.y, red);
        }
        previewHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
}
```

With this code I keep getting this error:

```
09-03 19:35:42.743: E/SurfaceHolder(19394): Exception locking surface
09-03 19:35:42.743: E/SurfaceHolder(19394): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
09-03 19:35:42.743: E/SurfaceHolder(19394):     at android.view.Surface.lockCanvasNative(Native Method)
09-03 19:35:42.743: E/SurfaceHolder(19394):     at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:76)
09-03 19:35:42.743: E/SurfaceHolder(19394):     at android.view.SurfaceView$4.internalLockCanvas(SurfaceView.java:744)
09-03 19:35:42.743: E/SurfaceHolder(19394):     at android.view.SurfaceView$4.lockCanvas(SurfaceView.java:720)
09-03 19:35:42.743: E/SurfaceHolder(19394):     at com.bluetooth.activities.MyActivity.onFaceDetection(MyActivity.java:90)
09-03 19:35:42.743: E/SurfaceHolder(19394):     at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:729)
09-03 19:35:42.743: E/SurfaceHolder(19394):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-03 19:35:42.743: E/SurfaceHolder(19394):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-03 19:35:42.743: E/SurfaceHolder(19394):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-03 19:35:42.743: E/SurfaceHolder(19394):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-03 19:35:42.743: E/SurfaceHolder(19394):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-03 19:35:42.743: E/SurfaceHolder(19394):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-03 19:35:42.743: E/SurfaceHolder(19394):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-03 19:35:42.743: E/SurfaceHolder(19394):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-03 19:35:42.743: W/dalvikvm(19394): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a561f8)
09-03 19:35:42.766: E/AndroidRuntime(19394): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-03 19:35:42.766: E/AndroidRuntime(19394): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
09-03 19:35:42.766: E/AndroidRuntime(19394):    at android.view.Surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(Native Method)
09-03 19:35:42.766: E/AndroidRuntime(19394):    at android.view.SurfaceView$4.unlockCanvasAndPost(SurfaceView.java:775)
09-03 19:35:42.766: E/AndroidRuntime(19394):    at com.bluetooth.activities.MyActivity.onFaceDetection(MyActivity.java:99)
09-03 19:35:42.766: E/AndroidRuntime(19394):    at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:729)
09-03 19:35:42.766: E/AndroidRuntime(19394):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-03 19:35:42.766: E/AndroidRuntime(19394):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-03 19:35:42.766: E/AndroidRuntime(19394):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-03 19:35:42.766: E/AndroidRuntime(19394):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-03 19:35:42.766: E/AndroidRuntime(19394):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-03 19:35:42.766: E/AndroidRuntime(19394):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-03 19:35:42.766: E/AndroidRuntime(19394):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-03 19:35:42.766: E/AndroidRuntime(19394):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is there a problem with the camera trying to draw its preview on the same SurfaceView the face detection callback? How can I do this without layering SurfaceViews?

Comment: I added a bounty to this because from digging in the Android source it looks like the preview runs on a different thread than the rest of the app, which I believe means that your app can't get a Canvas object, or lock the Surface, because they are different threads.  That said, I'm hoping someone who's dealt with this will respond

Comment: How about using a FrameLayout on top of all these views with a transparent background!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't lock and draw on a `SurfaceView` which has `Type.PUSH_BUFFERS`, (the one you're displaying frames to). You have to create another view above your original one in the Z direction and draw on a `SurfaceView` in that `View`.

So in your `main.xml` create a custom view below your original view in a `FrameLayout`.

Create and handle a `SurfaceView` in your Activity View. Add this view to the Camera preview display. Start your custom view passing the `SurfaceHolder`. In this view you can lock and draw on a canvas.

Answer (score 6):

As James pointed out you need to create custom surface which extends SurfaceView (I usually implement SurfaceHolder.Callback also):

`public class CameraSurfacePreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback`

Constructor will be something like:

```
public CameraSurfacePreview(Context context) {
     super(context);
     ...
     mHolder = getHolder();
     mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
     ...
```

You need to bind camera with your surface after camera open call (if you implement implements SurfaceHolder.Callback put this somewhere inside overridden surfaceCreated):

```
mCamera = Camera.open();
mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
```

Finally you need to add instance of your custom surface somehere in activity content view:

```
CameraSurfacePreview cameraSurfacePreview = new CameraSurfacePreview(this);
//camera surface preview is first child!
((ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.cameraLayout)).addView(cameraSurfacePreview, 0);
```

In my example layout for activity looks something like(I am showing camera preview in main frame layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"        
                      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_gravity="top|left"
              android:id="@+id/cameraLayout">
```

Answer (score 0):

I could said,

It's not about a Thread.

It not because of this line that make error either.

```
canvas.drawPoint(leftEye.x, leftEye.y, red);
```

It because of the canvas still using and can't lock it

If you carefully check, you will see this canvas you get is == null

```
canvas = canvasHolder.lockCanvas();
    if (canvas == null)  Log.i("Error", "Canvas == null!");
```

You might have question then where is it already use?

It already use to display to show what's going on to you! That is

```
camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
```

So, I suggest, If you want to draw Point over your eye, you might need to have another SurfaceView / SurfaceHolder over you SurfaceView for preview camera :]

Answer (score 0):

The lockcanvas/unlockcanvasandpost approach is not appropriate when using openGL as the openGL code is controlling and locking the surface. If you want to use the standard 2d APIs, don't use OpenGL.